# Overlapping sub menu ul li's

Tags: css, menu, html-lists

my problem is rather simply explained, but I just cannot find the answer using firebug etc....

Why are my submenu items overlapping? Hover over "Aktuelles" and you can see that the transparent submenu items overlap, creating ugly white bars. The ul li elements have no minus margins assigned to them, so why are they doing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are giving `.main-navigation li` a fixed height. Line 946 in style.css. Remove the height. Also the box-shadow on `.main-navigation li ul li a` might cause some ugly design. You'd better apply the shadow on `.main-navigation li ul`.

Comment: ah yes, and the fixed height was in conflict with the variable height from li a - thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score 1):

The `line-height` of a `<a>` is higher than it's parent `<li>`.

Set the `line-height` in the following classes to equal values:

```
.main-navigation li ul li a
.main-navigation li
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this css class:

```
.main-navigation li ul li a:hover {
background: #e3e3e3;
color: #444;
}
```

Change it like this:

```
.main-navigation li ul li a:hover {
background: #e3e3e3;
color: #444;
opacity: 0.75;
}
```

Comment: I am actually using a rgb background colour like this:
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
opacity pretty much the same - but since the layers are overlapping it leads to the white bars. I do not understand why the layers are overlapping... the transparency is not the issue.

Comment: because you set `background: #e3e3e3;` in `.main-navigation li ul li a:hover` class, you should omit it

Answer (score 0):

@Bram Vanroy answer is the way to go...

Also try this code

```
.sub-menu li {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Because `.main-navigation li` style affects all the `li` in that menu, so this `margin: 0 2.857142857rem 0 0` is making the `.sub-menu li` to have an ugly `margin-right`